# Subdomain argument is ignored in my links, so all links are prepend with request.subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, subdomain

I have a `Ruby on Rails 4` website that I wish to split up in `domain.com` and `mysubdomain.domain.com`. I am using `lvh.me` for testing.

My routes file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    get "first_page" => "pages#first_page", :as => :first_page

    constraints subdomain: "mysubdomain" do
      get "second_page" => "pages#second_page", :as => :second_page
    end

    root :to => 'pages#index'

  end
end
```

In my view file I have:

```
= link_to "First page",  first_page_path
= link_to "Second page", second_page_path(:subdomain => "mysubdomain")
```

But the `subdomain` argument is apparently ignored. Instead all links gets prepend with `request.subdomain`.

So if e.g. I am on:

```
http://mysubdomain.lvh.me:3000/second_page
```

Then the links on the webpage are as follows:

```
http://mysubdomain.lvh.me:3000/first_page   # Not as intended
http://mysubdomain.lvh.me:3000/second_page  # As intended
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using the `_path` helper and not the `_url` helper. The former generates a relative path so the site will use the current host where as the latter generates a full URL.

```
= link_to "Second page", second_page_url(subdomain: "mysubdomain")
```

should do what you're looking for.